# Using cookies in laravel to get referral code id?

Tags: laravel, cookies, referrals

I have generated a referral code for each user on my platform, and would to use cookies to track if a new user has signed up through someone else(aka. they got referred).

I can generate a url fine, i.e., http://localhost:8888/Test/public/?ref=111222333444

But the cookie doesn't appear to be storing and translating back to my database when I use the code to sign up as a new user

What am I missing?

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Closure;

class CheckReferral
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if( $request->hasCookie('referral')) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else {
        if( $request->query('ref') ) {
          print "yes cookie detected";
            return redirect($request->fullUrl())->withCookie(cookie()->forever('referral', $request->query('ref')));
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this was my dumb mistake - I overlooked adding the Middleware to my route. Solved it simply by doing this:

```
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckReferral;


Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
})->middleware(CheckReferral::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use middleware is to add it in `Kernal` class by setting it against `routeMiddleware` array e.g

```
$routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Laravel\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'guest' => \Laravel\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

    ...

    'check-referral' => \Laravel\Http\Middleware\CheckReferral::class,
];
```

and then assign the route e.g

```
Route::get('/', function () {
//
})->middleware('check-referral');
```

Hope this will help